# How to push from one local branch to all remote branch in github?

Tags: git, branch

I have more than 4 remote branches in my git repository.
My goal is to push one code into all these branches with a git command.

So I want like following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Do all with one command"
git push origin -all
```

Of course, the command above might not work properly.

Can I do this kind of action with only 3 commands like above?

Comment: Well you could just push each one separately, but place the git push logic into a single script, and then execute that script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already *is* a `git push --all` (note the double hyphen), but it's probably, or at least perhaps, not what you want.  The real problem here is that you have not properly defined what it *is* that you want—or at least, *I'm* not entirely sure what you want to achieve here.  The particularly confusing part, to me, is that this:

> ```
> git add .
> git commit -m "Do all with one command"
> ```

makes only *one* new commit, on the *current branch*.  If you then use `git push` to send this one new commit, but want to send it to "four branches", that's probably not going to do what you wanted.

Had you used, say:

```
for branch in br1 br2 br3 br4; do
    git checkout $branch
    [do some editing and/or cherry-picking and so on here]
    git commit
done
```

so that you had updates to your local branches named `br1`, `br2`, `br3`, and `br4`, and you now want to send *four* (or more) commits to the four corresponding branches on `origin`, *now* it would all make sense.

For that matter, here:

```
git push --all origin
```

might do precisely what you wanted.  However, it might do *more* than you want, since it means the same as:

```
git push origin "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"
```

i.e., use *all* your local branch names to send requests to the other Git for the same name.  If you had branches `br5` and `br6` as well, that would have the effect of sending any new commits on those branches, and asking `origin` to update its branch names that are spelled the same as yours.

If this is indeed what you want to do, consider using `--all` or an explicit *refspec* as in the above `git push`.  You can also change your `push.default` setting to `matching`.  Most users probably *should not* use the `matching` setting.  This was the default in Git 1 and was changed to `simple` in Git 2 because it was wrong for most users, but no one individual is ever "most users".

Comment: What I just want here is to use only one local branch "main" so that I can use one "commit" command. And I want to push from this "main" branch to all remote branches. You might probably feel strange about my unusual goal but I just want this now. Can you help me?

Comment: If you successfully push one commit to four branches, you will usually discard commits from three of those branches. That's not a good idea (which is why `--force` would be required). Don't do it.

Comment: The only exception to this rule is if you want to *merge* all four branches (which you'd normally do with three `git merge` commands, or one `git merge` using an octopus merge). The resulting final merge would then be a fast-forward for all four branches. You can push that in one command using explicit refspecs (and no `--force` option). But this is not what you showed above.

Answer (score 1):

If your remote is `origin`, you are on the `master` branch, remote branches are `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth`:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Do all with one command"
git push origin master:first master:second master:third master:fourth
```